# Java Class path problem in cent os

Tags: centos

I  have installed java in centos5 classpath is not working ....
my bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03/bin/java/
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/zzz/aa/mysql.jar:.

java -version 

java version "1.6.0"
OpenJDK  Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-b09)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 1.6.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working? I presume you actually mean that you want to use JDK 1.6.03 (Sun JDK) but you're getting Open JDK 1.6.09?

Comment: Also, can you specify how you installed JDK 1.6.03. RPM or Tarball?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

if your trying to run a different version of java.

Answer (score 0):

The CLASSPATH is declared incorrectly. It should be:

> export
>   CLASSPATH=/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03/lib/tools.jar:.:/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03/lib/dt.jar:/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03/jre/lib/rt.jar:/zzz/aa/mysql.jar

Now, it will work fine. You need to include basic JAR files from your JDK as well.

Comment: Also, JAVA_HOME should be:
export JAVA_HOME=/zzz/jdk1.6.0_03

Comment: I've never had to include systems libs to the classpath. Furthermore, I've found JAVA_HOME to extraneous in most situations.